# No recordar Credenciales de Login

Tags: html, login

Tengo un formulario de login y no deseo que las credenciales de email y contraseña queden en autocompletar es decir, que cuando el usuario llegue al formulario este esté en blanco sin los datos del usuario anterior o de el mismo, ya ensaye con

```
autocomplete="off"
```

en el `form` y en los `input` pero no funciona

Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Es correcto, en las dos entradas se pregunta lo mismo y las respuestas dadas en ese entonces y las que han dado a mi pregunta ahora se complementan, aun así no hay una solución definitiva al interrogante. Gracias por sus repuestas

Comment: La respuesta a esa pregunta (de la cual esta es duplicada, @fedorqui) está marcada como correcta y sin embargo no funciona en Chrome 61. Me suena incorrecto que los visitantes entren a esta pregunta y vayan a la original y vean una respuesta que no funciona.

Answer (score 3):

El uso de

```
autocomplete="off"
```

o

```
autocomplete="false"
```

Y otras variantes del atributo autocomplete han pasado a ser ignoradas en las versiones más recientes de Chrome y Firefox, bajo la premisa de que **el usuario debe decidir si guarda o no el password**, y dado que los browsers hoy en día guardan la contraseña internamente. Antiguamente se añadía un checkbox "recordarme" que implementaba esa funcionalidad a mano, ya sea usando una cookie o un valor en LocalStorage, pero era inseguro y desaconsejado.

A mí lo que me ha resultado es poner los input con atributo `readonly`, y añadir un listener que quita el readonly cuando el usuario pincha el input.

En el fondo tu input quedaría como:

```
<input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
```

Cuando se elimine el atributo `readonly`, sin embargo, el browser volverá a ofrecer autocompletar la contraseña mediante su funcionalidad nativa (Google Smart Lock en el caso de Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de navegadores ya no soportan `autocomplete="off"`

Prueba a sustituirlo por `autocomplete="new-password"`

Comment: Si Hechi, con esa propiedad el formulario se muestra vacio, pero si se le da doble clic en el campo del email aparecen los datos...